# XSD definition for empty or null object type

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to remove XML tag from XML output if it is null or empty list.  Is there a way where we can define in XSD file to not add in XML file if that particular List or object is null or empty. For example: 
`<MergerList></MergerList>`; Here it has no value to be displayed so I want it to be removed using xsd definition. Of course I can do using check in my code but I want it be done using XSD definition.

Comment: </mergerlist> is empty so that should not be part of XML to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to remove XML tag from XML output if it is null or empty list.  Is there a way where we can define in XSD file to not add in XML file if that particular List or object is null or empty.

No, not ***directly***.  An XSD's job is to validate that an XML file meets vocabulary and grammar constraints.  It does, itself, add or remove elements.

However, you can use an XSD to specify that an element may not be empty.  For example, `MyString` could be required to have a length greater than `1`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyString">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Or `MergeList` could be required to have at least one child element:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MergeList">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Merge" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

To ***directly*** remove empty elements, you'd have to write code to parse the XML and remove them.  XSLT is a good tool for this; hint: modify the identity transform to copy over all but the empty element in question.

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh

This can be implemented by setting restrictions on the fields so that they will not validate if they are present yet empty. These will not automatically remove the fields, if you use validation however you will force the client to send the message they way you want it. XSD cannot remove the field for you since it is only a definition, not a parser.

For example if you only want mergerlists that contain 1 or more entries, and if not you do not want a merger list than you can put that in your schema as follows.

```
<xs:element name="Mergerlist" type="MergerListType" minOccurs="0"/>

  <xs:complexType name="MergerListType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="merger"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now the merger element has the default minOccurs of 1. Zo a mergerlist with no merger is invalid. However having no mergerlist is valid because the mergerlist has minOccurs of 0.

When it comes to elements you can use restrictions as follows:

```
 <xs:element name="notNullField" minOccurs="0" type="minimalString"/>

  <xs:simpleType name="minimalString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

It is important however to keep in mind the proper way to  indicate a null value in xml is as follows:

```
 <Element xsi:nil="true"/>
```

In your xsd you would define this field like:

```
 <xs:element name ="Element" nillable="true"/>
```

With this the client can properly indicate a null value and differentiate between null or an empty string.

This would allow you to create a field that has to have a minimum length, or be null like this:

```
 <xsd:element name="notNullField" nillable="true" type="tns:minimalString"/>

  <xsd:simpleType name="minimalString">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:minLength value="1" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

This however still does not remove the fields, and this will not happen automatically. This can be done using a transfomation however. There are plenty examples on how to remove empty nodes using xslt on stackoverflow for example here.

So basicly your options are:

- Force your client to send the XML message you want using the xsd.
  (preferable)
- Use an xsl transformation to get rid of the empty elements
- Write code that deals with empty nodes.

Comment: Thanks for answer my query.In my case <MergerList></MergerList> is complext type.

Comment: That should not make too much of a difference. The principles remain the same. However I will update the example.  If you could add the example of your xsd as it is now would make it even easier.